# Datos duplicados en CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta y mis datos se duplican:

```
WITH Res1 AS
                (select 
                  detAct.FEC_FECINI
                , detAct.ID_EMPL
                , catU.NOM_USUARIO
                , detAct.ESTA_RES
                , CASE DATEPART(MONTH, detAct.FEC_FECINI)
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'ENE' 
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'FEB' 
                    WHEN 3 THEN 'MAR' 
                    WHEN 4 THEN 'ABR' 
                    WHEN 5 THEN 'MAY' 
                    WHEN 6 THEN 'JUN' 
                    WHEN 7 THEN 'JUL' 
                    WHEN 8 THEN 'AGO' 
                    WHEN 9 THEN 'SEP' 
                    WHEN 10 THEN 'OCT' 
                    WHEN 11 THEN 'NOV' 
                    WHEN 12 THEN 'DIC' 
                    END as Mes
                , DATEPART(WEEK, detAct.FEC_FECINI) as nSemana
                , count(DATEPART(WEEK, detAct.FEC_FECINI)) as total
                from DETA_ACTIVIDADES as detAct
                INNER JOIN CAT_USUARIO catU on detAct.ID_EMPL = catU.ID_CAT_USUARIO
                where DATEPART(YEAR, detAct.FEC_FECINI) = 2021
                and DATEPART(WEEK, detAct.FEC_FECINI) = 14
                and detAct.COD_ESTATUS = 1
                and detAct.ESTA_RES = 1
                and catU.COD_ESTATUS =1
                group by  detAct.FEC_FECINI, detAct.ID_EMPL, detAct.ESTA_RES, catU.NOM_USUARIO)

                , Res2 AS
                (select 
                  detAct.FEC_FECINI
                , detAct.ID_EMPL
                , catU.NOM_USUARIO
                , detAct.ESTA_RES
                , CASE DATEPART(MONTH, detAct.FEC_FECINI)
                    WHEN 1 THEN 'ENE' 
                    WHEN 2 THEN 'FEB' 
                    WHEN 3 THEN 'MAR' 
                    WHEN 4 THEN 'ABR' 
                    WHEN 5 THEN 'MAY' 
                    WHEN 6 THEN 'JUN' 
                    WHEN 7 THEN 'JUL' 
                    WHEN 8 THEN 'AGO' 
                    WHEN 9 THEN 'SEP' 
                    WHEN 10 THEN 'OCT' 
                    WHEN 11 THEN 'NOV' 
                    WHEN 12 THEN 'DIC' 
                    END as Mes
                , DATEPART(WEEK, detAct.FEC_FECINI) as nSemana
                , count(DATEPART(WEEK, detAct.FEC_FECINI)) total
                from DETA_ACTIVIDADES as detAct
                INNER JOIN CAT_USUARIO catU on detAct.ID_EMPL = catU.ID_CAT_USUARIO
                where DATEPART(YEAR, detAct.FEC_FECINI) = 2021
                and DATEPART(WEEK, detAct.FEC_FECINI) = 14
                and detAct.COD_ESTATUS = 1
                and detAct.ESTA_RES is Null
                and catU.COD_ESTATUS =1
                group by detAct.FEC_FECINI, detAct.ID_EMPL, detAct.ESTA_RES, catU.NOM_USUARIO)

                SELECT 
                  Res1.ID_EMPL
                , Res1.NOM_USUARIO as Ejecutivo
                , Res1.nSemana
                , sum(Res1.total) as Res1
                , sum(Res2.total) as Res2
                FROM Res1 left join Res2
                on Res1.ID_EMPL = Res2.ID_EMPL AND Res1.nSemana=Res2.nSemana AND Res1.Mes=Res2.Mes
                GROUP BY  Res1.ID_EMPL, Res1.NOM_USUARIO, Res1.nSemana
```

Para la primera consulta los resultados son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para la segunda los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el CTE final se muestra de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el usuario luis.ramirez en Res1 se debería de mostrar 2 y no 4 cómo está sucediendo hasta el momento. Me queda claro que es el único usuario que coincide en ambas consultas pero no logró entender porque se está calculando mal el resultado.

Comment: Como consejo, en una próxima, publica tus datos en formato de texto... realmente hay que tener mucha motivación para escribir una respuesta cuándo el propio interesado la hace tan difícil de responder, por lo complicado de producir alguna prueba de concepto, necesaria antes de responder.

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente la ayuda brindada y sobre todo gracias por explicar con tanta claridad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La lógica de la consulta final está fallando. Según entiendo lo que tu quieres es obtener la un resumen con la suma de lo que tienes en cada una de las consultas `Res1` y `Res2` *por separado* y, al hacer *join* antes de resumir, por cada fila que aparezca en `Res2` se van a repetir todos los datos de `Res1`.

El dato no se duplicaría, sino se cuadruplicaría, pero además estás *metiendo* el `mes` en la comparación, cosa que, de acuerdo al resultado que buscas, también es incorrecto.

Para lograrlo, puedes *resumir* primero dichas consultas y hacer el *join* para obtener el informe final hasta después de haber hecho este paso, algo en la línea de:

```
with
Res1 as (
/*tu consulta actual*/
)
, Res2 as (
/*tu consulta actual*/
)
,
ResumenRes1 as (
select id_empl
     , nom_usuario
     , nsemana
     , sum(total) Res1
  from Res1
 group by id_empl, nom_usuario, nsemana
)
,
ResumenRes2 as (
select id_empl
     , nom_usuario
     , nsemana
     , sum(total) Res2
  from Res2
 group by id_empl, nom_usuario, nsemana
)
SELECT   Res1.ID_EMPL
       , Res1.NOM_USUARIO as Ejecutivo
       , Res1.nSemana
       , Res1.Res1
       , Res2.Res2
  FROM ResumenRes1 Res1 
       left join ResumenRes2 Res2 on Res1.ID_EMPL = Res2.ID_EMPL AND Res1.nSemana=Res2.nSemana
```

Como he dicho antes, lo que hago es *resumir* primero cada consulta, para obtener la sumatoria por semana de cada empleado y, hasta entonces, hago el *join* de ambos resúmenes, ya sin aplicar ningún agrupamiento.

En mis pruebas, obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
ID_EMPL     Ejecutivo    nSemana     Res1        Res2
----------- ------------ ----------- ----------- -----------
1002        luis.ramirez 14          2           11

(1 row affected)


Completion time: 2021-04-19T13:20:13.1640352-06:00
```

Si resulta que si quieres incluir el mes, ajusta las consultas, pero en ese caso, `Res1` te va a dar 1 en la semana 14 en Marzo y 1 en Abril, mientras que Res2 te va a dar 10 en marzo y 1 en Abril.